# In Azure - Dashboard Designer connectivity to an SSAS data source

Tags: azure, ssas, designer, dashboard, performancepoint

In MS Azure, when I started preparing PerformancePoint Services on SharePoint 2013, the first step listed was

Install ADOMD.NET from the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack

I could not install ADOMD.NET in the SQL Server Azure environment.  Azure would not let me.  I performed all the other steps and began to configure Dashboard Designer Data Source to connect to SSAS.  When I couldn't connect I researched and found others in a non-Azure environment that recommended ADOMD.net.  What is the Azure solution to allow connectivity between Dashboard Designer and Analysis Services.  FYI - I can connect to Analysis Services through Excel 2010 through 80, 2383, and through SharePoint Excel Services.

What does ADOMD do that I need to do in another way or find a way to install it in an Azure environment?

Answer (score 0):

ADOMD provides the API's for connecting to SSAS. Without that, you can not connect to cubes.

How are you deploying this in Azure? In a hosted Hyper-V image?